combine components and views in a single file
In order to combine the components and views for a small vue app in a single file I use this
        manualChunks: {
          VueStuff: ['vuetify', 'vue', 'vue-router', 'pinia', 'vue-i18n'],
          VueComponents: ['@/components', '@/views'],
        }

Yet wenn building is see the following error
[vite:load-fallback] Could not load /home/J/Projects/webpage/src/components: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
at async readFileHandle (node:internal/fs/promises:553:24)
at async Object.load (file:///home/J/Projects/webpage/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@5.4.11/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-CB_7IfJ-.js:65091:25)
at async PluginDriver.hookFirstAndGetPlugin (file:///home/J/Projects/webpage/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@4.27.3/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:20709:28)
at async file:///home/J/Projects/webpage/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@4.27.3/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:19829:33
at async Queue.work (file:///home/J/Projects/webpage/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@4.27.3/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:20919:32)

How can I successfully combine my app in one file?

You can disable chunking with output.inlineDynamicImports: true

thanks! that hinted me in another direction and that is making big chunks might not be a good idea in the first place as dynamic loading would allow the application to be loaded quick initially. A valuable answer.
